# How to automatically get and send User's geolocation values as a POST request to the backend

Tags: javascript, reactjs, geolocation

I'm a junior front-end developer building a react web form with formik that automatically gets the user's location and sends it as a post request to the back end. I've been able to use the geolocation API to get the latitude and longitude of the user, but don't know how to pass it as an object and a post request.

This is for an e-commerce website that provides the user different services based on businesses nearby.

```
class DriverForm extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      ready: false,
      where: { lat: null, lng: null },
      error: null
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    //automatic location finder code goes here
    const geoOptions = {
      enableHighAccuracy: true,
      timeOut: 20000,
      maximumAge: 60 * 60 * 24
    };
    this.setState({ ready: false, error: null });
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      this.geoSuccess,
      this.geoFailure,
      geoOptions
    );
  }

  geoSuccess = position => {
    console.log(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
    this.setState({
      ready: true,
      where: { lat: position.coords.latitude, lng: position.coords.longitude }
    });
  };

  geoFailure = err => {
    this.setState({ error: err.message });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <div id="map" />
        <div className="form-position">
          <h1 className="signupHeader">Driver Sign up</h1>
          <Formik
            initialValues={{
              firstName: "",
              lastName: "",
              email: "",
              phone: "",
              password: "",
            }}
            validationSchema={DriverSchema}
            onSubmit={values => alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2))}
          >
            {({
              handleSubmit,
              handleChange,
              handleBlur,
              values,
              setFieldValue,
              isSubmitting,
              handleReset
            }) => (
              <Form>
                <div className="name-field-position">
                  <br />
                  <ErrorMessage
                    className="error"
                    name="firstName"
                    component="span"
                    style={{ color: "red" }}
                  />
                  <Field
                    name="firstName"
                    type="text"
                    className="inner-field-spacing field-display"
                    placeholder="Your First Name"
                    style={{ textAlign: "center", color: "purple" }}
                    id="firstName"
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    onBlur={handleBlur}
                    value={values.name}
                  />
                  <br />
                  <ErrorMessage
                    className="error"
                    name="lastName"
                    component="span"
                    style={{ color: "red" }}
                  />
                  <Field
                    name="lastName"
                    type="text"
                    className="inner-field-spacing field-display"
                    placeholder="Your Last Name"
                    style={{ textAlign: "center", color: "purple" }}
                    id="lastName"
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    onBlur={handleBlur}
                    value={values.name}
                  />
                </div>
                <br />
                <ErrorMessage
                  className="error"
                  name="email"
                  component="span"
                  style={{ color: "red" }}
                />
                <Field
                  name="email"
                  type="email"
                  className="inner-field-spacing field-display"
                  placeholder="janedoe@email.com"
                  style={{ textAlign: "center", color: "purple" }}
                  id="email"
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  onBlur={handleBlur}
                  value={values.name}
                />
                <br />
                <ErrorMessage
                  className="error"
                  name="password"
                  component="span"
                  style={{ color: "red" }}
                />
                <Field
                  name="password"
                  type="password"
                  className="inner-field-spacing field-display"
                  placeholder="password"
                  style={{ textAlign: "center", color: "purple" }}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  onBlur={handleBlur}
                  value={values.name}
                />

                 ......

                <a href="/" className="button-flex">
                  <button
                    className="registerButton2"
                    type="submit"
                    disabled={isSubmitting}
                  >
                    Become A Driver
                  </button>
                </a>
              </Form>
            )}
          </Formik>
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default DriverForm;
```

Comment: Take a look at the `fetch` API. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Comment: Thanks, I'll do that now.

Comment: @Jaxi thanks for the direction, I understand it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

inside your `onSubmit` props send a post request using `fetch` or I personally prefer axios to your backend URL:

```
onSubmit{values => {
  const request = axios.post({url, values})
  request.then("handle your response in here")
}}
```